# Select condition based record in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have below two tables and want to fetch name based on condition

```
table1 (id, display_name, org_id, a_type_id)
table2 (id, type_name, type_id)
```

To check in `table1`, fetch `display_name` with `where` condition:

```
org_id => '123' 
a_type_id = '123'
```

If `display_name` is not set or null **or no entry in this table**, check in `table2`, fetch type_name with `where` condition:

```
type_id = '123'
```

Rather than using two seperate query, can I use `join` and `if` condition?

Comment: How are the tables connected? Which is the foreign key of `table2` to `table1`?

Comment: @dns_nx tables are connected using a_type_id and  type_id

Comment: @dns_nx table 2 is master and table 1 is related table which has foreign key a_type_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT display_name
FROM table1
WHERE org_id => '123' 
  AND a_type_id = '123'
UNION ALL
SELECT type_name
FROM table2
WHERE type_id = '123'
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM table1
                   WHERE org_id => '123' 
                     AND a_type_id = '123'
                     AND display_name IS NOT NULL )
```